# Ways to test an access modifier

Tags: move-lang

good morning, guys.
Is there a way to test the access modifier? e.g. ensure that create_block is public(fun)? afaik that's not possible to do in a unit test (as the 'expected failure'  test itself would not compile). is this something we could use the prover for?

Answer (score 0):

The access modifier is statically set in the compiler, so as you pointed out, you could have a unit test, to ensure that it is public, but there's not necessarily a way to test that it's not public.

I think this is particularly similar to other languages, just a compiler time check.

https://move-book.com/syntax-basics/function.html#function-visibility